# Is it possible to use Qt Style Sheets with promoted widgets in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qt-creator, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to do some heavy redeisgning of standard widgets using Qt Style Sheets. So after doing most of it manually for different widgets by `#objectName` selectors I've decided to group similar widgets in some way.

For example, I have multiple `QFrames` which act like headers in inner forms. And I want all of them to have the same stylesheet. One way of doing that is using naming convention (this is my fallback variant), i.e. `QFrame[objectName|="prefix_"]`. But I wanted to group my widgets by class. So I created simple placeholder class:

```
class HeaderFrame: public QFrame
{
public:
    HeaderFrame(QWidget *parent = NULL): QFrame(parent) {}
};
```

Which allowed me to promote all these `QFrames` to `HeaderFrames`. After that I've tried setting

```
HeaderFrame { background-color: red; }
```

stylesheet to MainWindow object itself (to make it act on all HeaderFrames) but it won't work. Nothing is changed in QtCreator form designer and nothing is changed after compiling an application. I've tried different variants of this stylesheet but nothing works.

So, is only Qt widgets (like QLabel, QFrame, etc.) are available for styling this way? Or there is some way to write stylesheet for your promoted widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes,it is possible. The only thing you should keep in mind - base for your derived widgets should support style sheets, and reimplement their PaintEvent carefully.

```
class Header1Label : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using QLabel::QLabel;
};
```

Stylesheet:

```css
Header1Label
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;   
}
```

Comment: Then how should I do it? I'm not reimplementing paintEvent() at all, so QFrame::paintEvent() would be used which perfectly works with stylesheets. All I want is to group stylesheets by promoted widget class name as shown in question.

Comment: like with built-in widgets. By their class names.

Comment: @Raiv Yes, you're right about forgetting Q_OBJECT macro. Sadly it won't anyway show applied stylesheet in QtCreator form designer. So I should use fallback variant with name prefixes selector.

Comment: You can see them in the running program, qt creator itself won't show it.

Comment: Yep. This way it would be much harder to fine-grain application design.

Comment: i removed style sheets from my code into separate file. So i can edit them and just restart my application. without rebuilding. You may try that too... That also will allow you to create skins just with changing of that file, if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add `class-name` to object's class property, which is QStringList, and use `.class-name` selector.